# BigVideo.js / Video.js: Check "if" video is running, else: show <div>

Tags: jquery, video.js

sometimes the my BigVideo.js background just doesn't start running. I can't reproduce the error, it just happens sometimes.

I'd like to show a div-box via jQuery, if the video doesn't start.

Something like this in peudo-code:

```
if video is not running
  fadein div.info after 5 seconds
endif
```

How do I realise the "if"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

suppose your BigVideo object named "BV":

```
if (!BV.getPlayer().paused()) {
    // show div-box
}
```